# How group by relationship attributes sailsjs

Tags: sails.js, grouping

We have two models, User and Group.

User:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {

    [...]

    memberOfGroups: {
      collection: 'group',
      via: 'members'
    }
  }
};
```

Group:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {

    [...]
    money: {type:number},

    members: {
      collection: 'user',
      via: 'memberOfGroups',
      dominant: true
    }
  }
};
```

How to group by user "memberOfGroups" ? 
I wanna sum money user in each group

Example:

Group 1 : 10$,
Group 2 : 30$

How to do that with that models?

Answer (score 0):

```
User.find().populate('memberOfGroups', {groupBy: ['money'], sum: ['money']})
```

Or any variant of that should work.

Please give me entire models and response JSON you want if you are not clear with my answer above.